# How do I prove that Mahatma Gandhi said the following?

Tags: quotes

We may know by means of a simple Google search that Gandhi said the following: “It is better to be violent, if there is violence in our hearts, than to put on the cloak of non-violence to cover impotence.” However, I need to academically refer to this quote (cite it). Does anyone know how I could do it?

I wish to know where was this statement made, or in which book.

Comment: It's in On non-violence, by Ghandi, edited by Merton. I don't know how to properly cite, so you'll have to research it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The credit really should go to CGCampbell on this one, because this passage does indeed come from Gandhi's "On Non-violence" originally published in 1964. Page 37 includes this semi-famous quote. Here is the link to a scan of the book. You will need to go to the section marked "Non-Violence True and False."

[Gandhi on Non-Violence](https://books.google.com/books?id=AIrLed2w1lkC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Thanks to C. G. Campbell for doing all the real work here.

Comment: You're quite welcome.

Comment: FWIW: Page numbers can move around based on the printing. In general it would probably be better to reference the chapter (which I think you did) and edition.